# show a spinner/block a knockout grid while drawing

Tags: knockout.js

I am rendering a html table via knockout and the foreach binding. When *sorting* the underlying observable array, the redraw can take a few seconds when there is a lot of data so I want to show a block/spinner over the grid until the redraw is done. Here is a *simplified* fiddle of my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmontgomery/bkcsR/

I can't use the `afterMove` because it fires for each row, not the entire foreach. I found a fork of knockout that gets really close: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/690. However it still doesn't seem to quite work because the page gets locked while redrawing so my spinner doesn't go up until after all the redrawing, at which time I need to remove it again anyway... any suggestions?

PS> I know there may be some user experience issues with all this but just humor me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using `setTimeout` plus this commit: "[Add a global before and after callback for foreach/template bindings](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/690)". Since I couldn't easily link to this custom build of knockout in my fiddle I used [Rustam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425787/rustam)'s code to accomplish the unblocking (however in my real code I like how clean seanami's `after` event on the `foreach/template` is). Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmontgomery/MvBBC/

The setTimeout allows enough time for the block code cover the grid before continuing on with the sort:

```
Grid.prototype.sort = function (column) {
    $("#mygrid").block({ message: '<div />', overlayCSS: { opacity: 0.1, borderRadius: '4px' }, css: { border: 'none', background: 'transparent'} });
    setTimeout(this.doSort.bind(this, column), 100);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

After sorting applied to an array you can know which item in the array is the last one.
Then in 'afterMove' event handler you wait for the moment when the item's element moved to its new position and hides your Progess mark.
Here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rustam/jdavU/8/

You can utilize both 'change' event of observableArray and 'afterMove' event of 'foreach' binding.

```
var lastMovedData = null;

Grid.prototype.onChange = function(value){
    lastMovedData = value && value.length ? value[value.length - 1] : null;
    console.log('show Progress image');
};

Grid.prototype.onAfterMove = function(value, index, data){

    //console.log('after move');

    if(lastMovedData && data.key == lastMovedData.key){
        console.log('hide Progress image. Last item\'s key: ' + data.key);
    }

};
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that does not require a custom build of knockout, i.e. using https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/690. However this solution still has the issue of throwing up the grid block **after** the grid is done sorting. See: http://jsfiddle.net/cmontgomery/jdavU/10/

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, have you looked into pagination?

Also i think you would get better perf avoiding the container less binding and applying it directly to tr.  Also can you avoid the template on the span and use the text binding on it instead?  You may need to make your data more polymorphic or make sure the column property name matches the date property name. 
 Such as

```
text: $parent[$data.propName]
```

As far as a mask, you can have a div with opacity absolute positioned over the grid and toggle it with a bool flag.  Ive done this in complex scenarios using a custom binding for it.  One problem here is the size of the grid is growing as it fills the first time.  It also looks like static data.  You may be able to come up with a clever binding that saves the Dom nodes for sort states.

Comment: I personally don't think pagination is a good user experience; I lean towards filtering instead. As for perf, I agree removing all the templates would speed it up _but_ I needed to create a grid that was easily re-usable throughout my site and the templates make it very flexible. As for the mask, I can't get a custom binding to work due to how I'm showing my items. In prod, my items list is actually a computed based off a filter, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/6TevL/24/. So far this strategy has caused some grief when trying animations like this mask or a row fade in.